# How to utilize resources fully

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am training a CNN to classify CIFAR-10 dataset using Tensorflow. I am running [06_CIFAR-10.ipynb](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials) Jupyter Notebook on an AWS p2.xlarge instance (1 GPU, 4 vCPUs, 61GB RAM). I set it up using [Ubuntu 14 Tensorflow AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0).

Training takes a long time. When I check system resources, I see that most of the resources are still available.

```
$ free -h
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           59G       3.5G        56G        15M        55M       854M
-/+ buffers/cache:       2.6G        57G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B


$ top
top - 18:10:47 up  1:53,  1 user,  load average: 0.47, 0.63, 0.69
Tasks: 134 total,   1 running, 133 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 19.1 us,  4.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 73.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  2.8 st
KiB Mem:  62881764 total,  3695184 used, 59186580 free,    56792 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   875028 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                       
 2282 ubuntu    20   0  0.099t 2.192g 202828 S 248.2  3.7 141:55.88 python3                                                                                       


$ nvidia-smi 
Sat May  6 18:12:28 2017       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.99     Driver Version: 352.99         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           On   | 0000:00:1E.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   54C    P0    67W / 149W |  11012MiB / 11519MiB |     54%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2282    C   /usr/bin/python3                             10954MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I detect where the bottleneck is? And, any recommendations to utilize all system resources?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tricks and improvements you can make to achieve high performance, such as ensuring you use a high performance input pipeline, and leverage software-pipelining techniques. Unfortunately, without further information about your specific setup, I am unable to diagnose further.

For background reading (tips and techniques to improve performance), please see:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide
- https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models
- https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/benchmarks

I recommend starting with the tensorflow benchmarks scripts that are open source and available at: https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks